If my partner committed suicide in a terribly violent way and altered my brain forever, can i sue his estate?
If my partner of 17 years, committed suicide in a terribly violent way and I found him, and it altered my brain forever, can I sue his estate?

just curious, are you named in the will?

If X decides to kill himself and throws himself in front of a driving train, can the train driver who suffered severe mental stress sue the estate for damages? I suspect the "partner for 17 years" might not matter.
